# Vim Tabular/Regular expression for aligning comma-separated arguments function

Tags: vim, arguments, alignment, vim-tabular

I would like to align comma-separated arguments so that only one argument is present per line. For instance, I would like to transform the following

```
mafInfo[[i]] <- maftools::read.maf(maf = mafInfo[[i]], vc_nonSyn = unlist(strsplit(params$nonSyn_list, 
¦   split = ",", fixed = TRUE)), removeDuplicatedVariants = params$remove_duplicated_variants,         
¦   gisticAllLesionsFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$all.lesions, gisticAmpGenesFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$amp.genes,
¦   gisticDelGenesFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$del.genes, gisticScoresFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$scores.gis,     
¦   verbose = FALSE)
```

into

```
mafInfo[[i]] <- maftools::read.maf(                                             
¦   maf = mafInfo[[i]],                                                         
¦   vc_nonSyn = unlist(strsplit(params$nonSyn_list, split = ",", fixed = TRUE)),
¦   removeDuplicatedVariants = params$remove_duplicated_variants,               
¦   gisticAllLesionsFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$all.lesions,                         
¦   gisticAmpGenesFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$amp.genes,                             
¦   gisticDelGenesFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$del.genes,                             
¦   gisticScoresFile = gisticInfo[[i]]$scores.gis,                              
¦   verbose = FALSE                                                             
)
```

which I can then align even more nicely with `Tabularize /=` to get

```
mafInfo[[i]] <- maftools::read.maf(                                                                   
¦   maf                             = mafInfo[[i]],                                                   
¦   vc_nonSyn                       = unlist(strsplit(params$nonSyn_list, split = ",", fixed = TRUE)),
¦   removeDuplicatedVariants        = params$remove_duplicated_variants,                              
¦   gisticAllLesionsFile            = gisticInfo[[i]]$all.lesions,                                    
¦   gisticAmpGenesFile              = gisticInfo[[i]]$amp.genes,                                      
¦   gisticDelGenesFile              = gisticInfo[[i]]$del.genes,                                      
¦   gisticScoresFile                = gisticInfo[[i]]$scores.gis,                                     
¦   verbose                         = FALSE                                                           
)
```

I would like to do this in several languages, not only in R. Could you help me please ?

Thank you,

Yoann

Comment: Usually it's easier to acquire some external "pretty-print" filter program and apply it directly to your buffer. Like `setlocal equalprg=r_pretty_print` and then pressing`5==`.